# Magento 1.9 - get order by id and customers that made the order

Tags: php, magento

I have following task to do (I have 0 magento experience, and I am told to do this):

Make standalone script that reads every order from Magento, and filter those that have purchased this product id => 297. Then write the customer and order information into a csv file on the server.

I know how to make CVS file, but I don't know how to work with magento. 
How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to load  Magento sale item collection by 
below code

```
    $itemCollection=Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_item_collection')
->getFieldToFliter('product_id',27)->addFieldToSelect('*');

    foreach($itemCollection as $item){
    var_dump($item->getData());
    /*load order */
    $order=Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($item->getData('order_id'));

    var_dump($item->getData());

    }
```

Comment: I am getting this error: Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Order_Item_Collection::getFieldToFiter() in /var/www/vhosts/sexperience.com.au/sex.mebsites.net/exportorders.php on line 10